# ¿Por qué 2^(n-1) - 1 es el menor valor de una variable de n bytes?

Tags: matemáticas, lógica, binario

Sabemos que la fórmula para calcular el rango de una variable primitiva con signo en C++ es:

min: `-(2^(n-1))`
max: `2^(n-1) -1`

Entiendo que a n se le deba restar 1, pues uno de los bits está siendo usado para determinar el signo. Lo que no entiendo es por qué el máximo es 2^(n-1) **-1**. ¡Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por que no hay un cero negativo entonces, con signo negativo tenés un número más.

Con dos bits:

```
01 = 1
00 = 0
11 = -1
10 = -2
```

O dicho de otra forma, con signo positivo tenés un número menos (el -1 de la fórmula).

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta tienes que encontrarla en la forma de codificar los dígitos numéricos. Los números negativos no tienen una representación directa en binario (el signo negativo no encaja). Así pues se requiere algún mecanismo que permita codificar los dígitos numéricos para que el procesador admita los números negativos.

Una de las coidficaciones más utilizadas es [complemento a 2](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_a_dos). Esta codificación tiene como particularidad que las operaciones aritméticas entre números positivos y negativos sean prácticamente triviales.